# The master link that came with my chain won't fit

Tags: chain, master-link

[image][image]

I have this master link that came with my chain (Snap On type). In the first picture it is distinctly the one on the left - not a spring clip.

Try as I might - it doesn't seem to be long enough? Do I need to use those funky chain pliers for it? How much can I compress that link? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to bend the chain. Look at [this link](http://www.connexchain.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Service_Downloads/Anleitungen/Montageanleitung_Snap_On_2015_englisch.pdf) (PDF) for the Connex Snap On which is the same idea. The PDF is reproduced below in case the thing goes down.

[image]

[image]

As an aside, you normally can get an alternative standard quick link (like a SRAM 8 speed powerlink) for these chains, rather than the Snap on type.